# I need to export all products and images but I don't know which table the images are in

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In the wp_posts table, the guid field does not display the url of the item's image, per the ID field. I have poked around in the other tables, but I just can't find it.  When I'm looking for a specific item (ID), the guid field displays what I believe is the permalink?  How can I export my items with the URL where the associated image is located?

Help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All images is stored in the `wp_posts` table with a `post_type` set to `attachment` e.g:

```
SELECT ID, post_type, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'

+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID   | post_type  | guid                                                                                      |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3507 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/965299442994c85c_org.jpg              |
| 3485 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ab7c1762d9245ea3_org.jpg              |
| 3483 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/a5e7f0092e77337d_org.png              |
| 3465 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/9213e34085be43c7_org.png              |
| 3463 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/acf63925ab2b7214_org.png              |
| 3459 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/aa72b09f84f61ebe_org.png              |
| 3073 | attachment | http://localhost:8000/wp/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/200811_164630923592737_4578052_n.jpeg |
| 3727 | attachment | http://localhost:8080/wp/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/woocommerce-placeholder.png           |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the `guid` is an URL pointing to where the image is located in your uploads directory.

Comment: note that the guid isn't always the URL of the image, and that it's a little more complicated than this. To reliably get the URL of an attachments original file you need to call PHP functions for the appropriate image size ( or specify `full` as the size ). In some cases the GUID may be out of date, refer to its permalink instead ( attachments can have meta/templates/comments ), or to a 3rd party URL